# Wordpress not reading cookies properly on load without hard refresh

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

I'm about to launch a redesign of my site that utilizes 2 cookies; one handles a dark mode switch, the other handles a first time visitor notice.

The problem is that the cookies aren't being read and acted upon on pages already visited. I've disabled all caching on my host.

Example: I visit the homepage and dismiss the first time visitor notice. It doesn't appear on any other page now. If I go back to the homepage, the first time visitor notice shows again. A hard refresh will load the page without the notice.

Example 2: I browse the site a bit, and then set the dark mode switch to dark mode. I visit a previously visited page, and it loads the page with light mode (dark/light mode is handled via a single class on the  tag). A hard refresh causes it to finally load dark mode.

Here's the relevant source:

From header.php, for the dark mode switch:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["darkmode"])){
    $cookie_name = "darkmode";
    $cookie_value = "0";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 365), "/", "localhost:5010"); // 86400 = 1 day
}

if ($_COOKIE["darkmode"]) {
    $extraBodyClass = "d4rkm0d3";
} else {
    $extraBodyClass = "";
}
```

$extraBodyClass is echo'd at the  tag.

For the notice in header.php:

```
if ($_COOKIE["glitchNoticeConfirm"]) {
    echo ' hide';
}
```

Here's how the cookies are handled on the JS side:

```
function darkModeSwitch() {
    if (jQuery("body").hasClass("d4rkm0d3")) {
        jQuery("body").removeClass("d4rkm0d3");
        document.cookie = "darkmode=0;path=/";
    } else {
        jQuery("body").addClass("d4rkm0d3");
        document.cookie = "darkmode=1;path=/";
    }
}

function glitch_hideNotice() {
    document.cookie = "glitchNoticeConfirm=1;path=/";
    jQuery(".glitch_notice").fadeOut();
}
```

Both are triggered here:

```
document.getElementById("glitch_toggleNav").addEventListener("click", glitch_toggleNav, false);
  document.getElementById("glitch_notice__dismissButton").addEventListener("click", glitch_hideNotice, false);
```

Comment: Update: Ignore the localhost domain in first code snippet, that was already fixed